# Accessing methods been classes

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

This is a really dumb question but how do I access methods from other classes. I've found I'm unable to pass the objects between classes like java because of static reference issues. In my research I've found delegates for methods which I thought might help like in Objective C but I either don't understand how they work or they are not relevant to my problem. I've also had a look at ref but that doesn't seem to help either but again my understanding of that is limited. Here's kinda what I want to do.

```
class foo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 
        Application.Run(new frmMainWindow());
    }

     public void callSomeMethod(Para)
     {
         //call someMethod from foo class - this step is my problem
     }
}

class bar
{
    public static bar()
    {
        //init
    }

    public void someMethod(para1, para2)
    {
        // bar.someMethod calls foo.CallSomeMethod
        callSomeMethod(Para);
    }
}
```

I know this is a basic question but I'm pretty stuck. I've spent a few hours fiddling and searching online. I know I'm missing something basic...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this code is self-describing. This is a simple console application, while not solving your exact problem, you should be able to see how the classes are interacting together and from here you hopefully will be able to craft your issue to work out for you.

```
public class Foo
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //new instance of Bar
        var bar = new Bar();

        //call method defined on Bar
        bar.SomeMethod("Hey", "There");
    }

    public static void MethodFromFoo(string param1, string param2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(param1 + ' ' + param2);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public void SomeMethod(string param1, string param2)
    {
        // call method on Foo -- no need for new instance (static)
        Foo.MethodFromFoo(param1, param2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry my example wasn't clear. I want to use callSomeMethod from bar to call Somemethod in foo. I'll update my OP to make this clearer

Comment: That was one of the early things I tried and it didn't work. I tried it again now and get this error. "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.findFundByName(string)'"

Comment: I've removed all static references from my program and still can't get rid of the error message.

Comment: Worked it out I had to refer to the method i was calling as static like your example.

Answer (score 0):

Its a Simple Mistake Often Commited

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
class foo
{

    static void Main(string[] args)  // Initial Solution
    {
           Application.EnableVisualStyles();
           " 
               "
    }

     public void callSomeMethod( r )
     {
          //call someMethod from foo class - this step is my problem
     }
}


class bar  
{

      public static bar()
      {
           //init
      }
       public void someMethod(r1 r2)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("r1: {0}",  r2.get());
           Console.ReadKey();   // Similar To Getch(); in C [ Hold The Answer ]
       }
}
```

Let Me Known If This Worked Or Not ?